# Batch script to monitor a service and automatically start the service if stopped. Need the output of to a logfile

Tags: batch-file, file-io, logfile

Batch script to monitor a service and automatically start the service if stopped. Need to write the output of the `net start` command into a logfile.
Executed the below script but failed to get the output into the log

```
net start | find /i "bits"
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" ( echo Service "Print Spooler" starting at %time% on %date% by Script 
%0>>C:\Users\DivyaBhargavMuddu\Desktop\ServiceRestart.Log
sc config "spooler" start=auto
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('net start spooler ') DO ( Set var=%%F)
Set /P var =< "C:\Users\DivyaBhargavMuddu\Desktop\ServiceRestart.Log"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working through below

```
net start | find /i "bits"
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" ( echo Service "bits" starting at %time% on %date% by 
Script %0>>C:\Users\DivyaBhargavMuddu\Desktop\ServiceRestart.Log
sc config "bits" start=auto
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('net start BITS ') DO ( Set var=%%F)
echo %var% >> "C:\Users\DivyaBhargavMuddu\Desktop\ServiceRestart.Log"
)
```